# Is this the best way to use $watch into multiple scope

Tags: angularjs, watch

I am developing an RGB slider and converting it to HEX afterwards. But this is the first time I used $watch and I'm not sure if this is the proper way to use it. It works but I have a little doubt on it.

```
$scope.colorRed = 0;
$scope.colorGreen = 0;
$scope.colorBlue = 0;

$scope.$watch('colorRed', function() {
  $scope.colorHex = rgbToHex($scope.colorRed, $scope.colorGreen, $scope.colorBlue);
});

$scope.$watch('colorGreen', function() {
  $scope.colorHex = rgbToHex($scope.colorRed, $scope.colorGreen, $scope.colorBlue);
});
$scope.$watch('colorBlue', function() {
  $scope.colorHex = rgbToHex($scope.colorRed, $scope.colorGreen, $scope.colorBlue);
});
```

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/645c59NhsLLhXpmEDxl8?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a watch, why not use an object to store the colors, and add a watch to track for property changes on the object.

```
$scope.color = {
  Red: 0,
  Blue:0,
  Green:0
}
```

and just use one watch.

```
$scope.$watch('color', function(color) { 
   $scope.colorHex = rgbToHex(color.Red, color.Green, color.Blue); //color will be same as $scope.color
}, true);
```

or:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $scope.color;
 }, function(color) {
    $scope.colorHex = rgbToHex(color.Red, color.Green, color.Blue);
}, true);
```

Comment: I have a question about the 3rd code block. What do you call that, is that a nested function?closure? or just a function?

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez that is another way to create a watch.. Basically if you specify a string angular is going to convert it internally to a function. We are just doing it before hand thats it... :)